# is it possible declare array property to object and instancely push in it?

Tags: javascript

I want to declare a variable that will have a property that is an array.and after that, I want to push some data to that property .

```
let a;
if(some condition){
   a.lists.push(...some_ids)
}
```

is this possible ? or I need to structure my object first with my **lists** property?

Comment: Why push? Why not just directly assign an array to the attribute?

Comment: @JonWarren cause I have many conditions inside my code that existence of them is relevant.I need to push to it

Comment: Could you just do something like `(a.lists === undefined) ? a.lists = [...some_ids] : a.lists.push(...some_ids)`?

Comment: @JonWarren tnx for the reply I know hot to push. my questions is it possible you declare property instantly and push it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a property with an array before you `push`, otherwise you will try to evaluate an expression `undefined.push()` (because variable `a` has no property named `list` and `a.list` will evaluate to `undefined`) and `TypeError` will be thrown

```js
let a = { list: [] }
if(someCondition){
   a.list.push(/* some ids here */)
}
```

Comment: I see now, its all about declaration first and assignment to it is after the declaration.I thought in my mind if we can assign a property to an object, maybe we  could push it too

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this;

```
let a = {};

if (true) {
  a['list'] = a['list'] ? [...a.list, ...someIds] : someIds;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `if (true)` condition?

Comment: an example... "@JonWarren cause I have many conditions inside"

Comment: Sorry, I see it now; makes sense